# Parse a CSV table from a variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, npm

I have a node application which can end up with a CSV formatted table in a variable.

I'd like to parse it into a JSON style format.

All of the modules I've looked at seem to only take input from files (unless I'm misunderstanding)

Are there any modules out there which do what I'd like or would I be better off just rolling my own solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example from NodeCSV seems to be parsing from a variable:

https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser

```
var csv = require('csv');
csv()
   .from( '"1","2","3","4"\n"a","b","c","d"' )
   .to( console.log )
```

In general, Node.js lets you treat both files and strings as streams. It's usually pretty trivial to go from one to the other.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could use [string.js](http://stringjs.com/). It works on Node.js and client side in the browser. Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Example:

```
var S = require('string');
S(myCsvData).lines().forEach(function(line){
  var fields = S(line).parseCSV();
});
```

Comment: I found that this is a much simpler and faster approach. Thanks!